# Compressing Image Files using gzip

Tags: python, gzip, zlib

I have .PNG files in a folder. I want to compress them and create .gz file.I appended the data but still it contains a single file for many compressed files. and as the zlib.compress() accept the string to compress so I have to read the data in from file and then have to compress it and write in the gz file. that eventually create the single file. But question comes is ,How do I decompress those files then again.

Tried out this much untill now:

```
gip = gzip.open("out.gz",'a')
for f in image_list:
   indata = open(f,'r').read()
   gip.write(zlib.compress(indata))
gip.close()
```

Comment: You seem to misunderstand `gzip`. It's a compression format, not an archive format, so it's not designed to compress multiple files at once. Use `zip` or `tar` for that (both in the Python stdlib).

Comment: Note, that since PNG uses already a compression scheme internally (depending on compression level), you will probably get no significant size reduction (if that was your primary aim).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gzip is only for compression of a single stream.  To maintain the structure of multiple files and directories, you need the tar format, which is usually compressed with gzip.  The resulting filename suffix is `.tar.gz`.

Use [`tarfile` in Python](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/tarfile.html), which will handle both the tarring and the gzipping.